# OpenWeek class for Ask Ubuntu?

Tags: discussion, site-promotion, ubuntu-community

It would be great if someone could volunteer to hold a class on how to use Ask Ubuntu, tips and tricks, etc. for Ubuntu Open Week. Ping me on chat if you're interested!

See:

- http://www.jorgecastro.org/2012/04/09/ubuntu-openweek-for-12-dot-04/

Comment: Wants,Pings @JorgeCastro